# Unable to display button in tableViewRow in titanium

Tags: cross-platform, titanium

i am new to titanium development.i am developing ToDo application using Titanium for learning purpose.i able to display the data from database and generate tableViewRow successfully but i am stuck in one phase that i unable to display button in each row.i did R&D for it but i cant get solution.here is my code for display buttons in each row of tableViewRow it display all records from database in each row but not buttons.it shows [object TableViewRow] in each row instead of button. so please help me to solve the issue

```
![Titanium.UI.setBackgroundColor('black');

var win = Titanium.UI.createWindow
({  
    title:'Tab 1',
    backgroundColor:'#fff'


});

var db = Titanium.Database.install('/mydata/ToDoDB', 'ToDoDB');
    var rows = db.execute('SELECT * FROM task');
    var data1=[];

    while(rows.isValidRow())
        {

         var rowview=Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow();

         var btn=Titanium.UI.createButton
         ({
                right:'20dp',
                width:'60dp',
                height:'40dp',
                title:'Show'

         });

         rowview.add(btn);

         var tt=rows.fieldByName('title');
         var cc=rows.fieldByName('content');
         //data1.push({title:rows.fieldByName('title')},{title:rows.fieldByName('content')},{title:rowview});
         data1.push({title:tt+cc+rowview});

         rows.next();
         //rowview.add(btn);
        };
        rows.close();
    var yourTable = Ti.UI.createTableView
    ({
        width : Ti.UI.FILL,
        height : Ti.UI.FILL,
        data: data1
    });

    db.close();
    win.add(yourTable);

    win.open();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
var rowview = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow();

var tt=rows.fieldByName('title');
var cc=rows.fieldByName('content');

var btn=Titanium.UI.createButton({
    right:'20dp',
    width:'60dp',
    height:'40dp',
    title:'Show'
});

var labeltt=Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    left:'20dp',
    width:'60dp',
    height:'40dp',
    text:tt
});

var labelcc=Titanium.UI.createLabel({
    left:'80dp',
    width:'60dp',
    height:'40dp',
    text:cc
});
rowview.add(labeltt);
rowview.add(labelcc);
rowview.add(btn);

data1.push(rowview);
```

*I didn't tried this code, so there should be some alignment issues.* I hope this will help you

Comment: i use yours code it works its shows button in each row but not shows lablett,labelcc .i am confuse please help to solve this issue

Comment: @user2522589: Oops!!! That was a mistake from me!!! I have used 'title' instead of 'text' property for labels. I have updated the code,  check it. Also try to change the position, I mean left, right, width, height of the labels. Also adjust the height of the row. Some times your controls may be missed due to that

Comment: i had marked the ann but it shows it required 15 reputation i recently open account

Comment: and one more think it shows tableviewrow with button its ok.bt hw would i show appropriate  lablecc values of each rows in alertbox when click in button.i use title:lablecc bt it shows only last values of table on same button

Comment: @user2522589:You dont need any reputation to accept an answer, but need 15 reputations to up vote for an answer. Just have a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Try to add an eventlistener to the tableview and try to access the text of label as (child[2].text as per my answer).

Comment: i add event listener on button which is in table row it shows alert dialog but i want show lablecc values on title property of alertdialog  i use title:cc it shows same value to all alertdialog.

Comment: It can be done simply
Make your button and label as an array as follows
var btn = [];
var labelcc = [];
var i=0;
Now inside while loop change the code as follows:
btn[i] = Ti.UI.createButton({//Your code here});
labelcc[i] = Ti.UI.createLabel({//Your code here});
btn[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
alert(labelcc[i].title);
//Your code here
});
i++;
rowview.add(labelcc[i]);
//blah blah

Try it.. This will do the trick

Comment: above code is worked but it not shown tablecc[i] values in alert dialog.when i print tablecc[i] values on console it shows undefined.btn[i].addEventListener('click',function(e)
   {
    
    Ti.API.info('res'+labelcc[i].title);
     var dialog =        Ti.UI.createAlertDialog
     ({
        cancel: 1,
        buttonNames: ['Confirm', 'Cancel', 'Help'],
        title:'Hi'+labelcc[i],
        //title: labelcc[i]
      }); how i get values of labelcc[i]

Comment: I also try with labelcc[i].text it shows Uncaught error:cannot read the property of text it is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is a custom row once you start including buttons and such.

Here is a old but still informative example

http://cssgallery.info/custom-row-for-tableview-in-appcelerator-titanium/

Basic idea is that you create a view, place it in the row, and then add the additional row UI object into that view

Comment: i able to show button on each tableview but my requirement is open alert dialog box on button click and display content of title to alert box .i able to show it but it doest show title:lablecc value in alert box.